# Combine two arrays by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
[15407] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15407
        [group] => 9083
        [value] => 60.00000
    )

[15473] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15473
        [group] => 9109
        [value] => -15.000000
    )

[15474] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15474
        [group] => 9109
        [value] => -20.000000
    )
)

Array
(
[15407] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15407
        [group] => 9083
        [value_prev] => 100.000000
    )

[15474] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15474
        [group] => 9109
        [value_prev] => -100.000000
    )

)
```

I'm trying to combine these arrays by the key and to add new element (value_prev) if match, or 0 if doesn't exist, so I need these arrays:

```
Array
(
[15407] => Array
(
    [id] => 15407
    [group] => 9083
    [value] => 60.00000
    [value_prev] => 100.000000
)

[15473] => Array
(
    [id] => 15473
    [group] => 9109
    [value] => -15.000000
    [value_prev] => 0
)

[15474] => Array
(
    [id] => 15474
    [group] => 9109
    [value] => -20.000000
    [value_prev] => -100.000000
)
)
```

I tried with array_keys function but couldn't get required array.
There are some solution I have found but non helped me cause the structure of the arrays is not the same.

Comment: You should post your attempt and not just "tried with...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the arrays are associative it's a very simple task.

Loop array one and see if the key exist in array 2, if it does copy value, else add 0 value.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $key => &$sub){
    if(in_array($key, $keys)){
        $sub["value_prev"] = $arr2[$key]["value_prev"];
    }else{
        $sub["value_prev"] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't give me expected array. I found solution with array_replace_recursive, it gives me almost good array, just missing value_prev 0. Thanks anyway

Comment: Now you made me test the code and rewrite your arrays, I don't like that! In what way does this differ from your expected output? https://3v4l.org/kdRaY @Pecooou